# Two Class Loaded by ClassLoader, They Can Not Call Each Other

Tags: java, classloader

Assume you have two java class

```
package package1;

public class SampleClass1 {

    public SampleClass1() {

        System.out.println("Sample Class Loaded and Called");
    }
}

package package1.package2;

import package1.SampleClass1;

public class SampleClass2 {

    public SampleClass2() {

        new SampleClass1();
        System.out.println("Sample Class 2 Loaded and Called");
    }
}
```

and load two classes by ClassLoader something like that:

```
package load;

public class LoadClassFromByteData extends ClassLoader {

    private byte[] classByteData;

    public LoadClassFromByteData(byte[] classByteData) {
        this.classByteData = classByteData;
    }

    public Class<?> getLoadedClass(String className) {

        return defineClass(className, classByteData, 0, classByteData.length);
    }
}
```

//

```
Class<?> loadedClass1 = loadClassFromByteData.getLoadedClass("package1.SampleClass1");
Class<?> loadedClass2 = loadClassFromByteData.getLoadedClass("package1.package2.SampleClass2");
```

when i call constructor of SampleClass1 like that:

```
Constructor<?> mainCons1 = loadedClass1.getConstructor();
mainCons1.newInstance();
```

successfully, printing "Sample Class Loaded and Called" but when i call constructor of loadedClass2 load from SampleClass2 byte data i have an error like:

```
Constructor<?> mainCons2 = loadedClass2.getConstructor();
mainCons2.newInstance();
```

// And yes, first i load SampleClass1 then i load SampleClass2, finally i call SampleClass2 constructor.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at db.recorder.deneme.main(deneme.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: package1/SampleClass1
    at package1.package2.SampleClass2.<init>(SampleClass2.java:9)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package1.SampleClass1
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:718)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

I want to add this information, two Classes byte data stored in DB, and i get byte data of classes from DB. Actually, the project has not any package named package1 or package2 !

Thanks for your answers and advices.

Comment: To me it seems that this is not the original code but a simplification that might not reflect the actual problem, unfortunately. I.e. you state that you use the same `loadClassFromByteData` object for loading both sample classes, but what are the bytes you feed the class with actually? May it be that you create a new `loadClassFromByteData` object, and therefore a class loader, per invocation? In that case the second call has probably no information on the first sample class and therefore throws the exception it does. Classloading is based on a delegation model which only loads classes if ...

Comment: ... neither of the ancestors loaded the bytes beforehand. You, therefore, either want to keep track of the loaded definition in your CL or use the loader that loaded your first sample class as CL-parent in the second one

Comment: Were you able to test my suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the parent classloader.

```
   public static class LoadClassFromByteData extends ClassLoader {

        final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Class<?>> definedClassesByName = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        LoadClassFromByteData(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(parent);
        }

        public Class<?> getLoadedClass(String className, byte[] classAsBytes) {

            return this.definedClassesByName.computeIfAbsent(className,
                    cn -> defineClass(cn, classAsBytes, 0, classAsBytes.length));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

        final byte[] sampleClass1Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(SAMPLE_CLASS1_CLASS_FILE_PATH);
        final byte[] sampleClass2Bytes = Files.readAllBytes(SAMPLE_CLASS2_CLASS_FILE_PATH);

        final ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
        final LoadClassFromByteData loadClassFromByteData = new LoadClassFromByteData(contextClassLoader);
        final Class<?> sampleClass1 = loadClassFromByteData.getLoadedClass("package1.SampleClass1", sampleClass1Bytes);
        final Object sampleClass1Instance = sampleClass1.newInstance();
        final Class<
            ?> sampleClass2 = loadClassFromByteData.getLoadedClass("package1.package2.SampleClass2", sampleClass2Bytes);
        final Object newInstance = sampleClass2.newInstance();
    }
```

Comment: Jeff, Thank you very much, when define a parent loader for loaded classes, it reference each other successfully...